# Add separator on number freemaker template

Tags: regex, templates, freemarker

Hi i m working with FreeMaker in a OpenOffice template , i just want to display in table a thousands separator for values example 
when i have : 12982,23 i want : 12 982,23 
when i have : 1234,2 i want  : 1 234,2
so i tried to create a macro with regex :

```
[#macro arrondi2decimales valeur][#if valeur?size > 0][#if valeur?length > 0]${valeur?number?string("###,##0.00")}[/#if][/#if][/#macro]
```

But not working for my table in OpenOffice template .

[image]
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
    <#assign x = "12000,2" />
    <#assign i = x?keep_before(",") />
    <#assign d = x?keep_after(",") />

    <#if (i?length > 3)>
       ${i[0..i?length-4] + " " + i[i?length-3..i?length-1]}${"," + d}
    <#else>
       ${x}
    </#if>
```

output: 12 000,2

Comment: I m trying to create a macro , but i have an error [#macro arrondi2decimalestest value]
      [#value i = valeur?keep_before(",") /]
      [#value d = valeur?keep_after(",") /]
  
      [#if (i?length > 3)]
         ${i[0..i?length-4] + " " + i[i?length-3..i?length-1]}${"," + d}
      [#else]
         ${value}
      [/#if]
  [/#macro

Comment: @zikyoubi there is no #value directive. use #assign and if the macro parameter is set as a string this will work

Comment: Sorry i did mistake , i tried this [#macro arrondi2decimalestest value]
      [#assign i = value?keep_before(",") /]
      [#assign d = value?keep_after(",") /]
  
      [#if (i?length > 3)]
         ${i[0..i?length-4] + " " + i[i?length-3..i?length-1]}${"," + d}
      [#else]
         ${value}
      [/#if]
  [/#macro]

Comment: I had this error java.rmi.RemoteException: Error on line 504, column 41, in template content.xml
Found keep_before, expecting one of:  date,  is_directive,  parent,  js_string,  j_string,  replace,  uncap_first,  float,  right_pad,  is_transform,  number,  datetime,  node_type,  split,  is_hash,  trim,  children,  has_content,  is_sequence,  xml,  html,  ancestors,  new,  last,  byte,  double,  left_pad,  sort,  matches,  capitalize,  contains,  eval,  lower_case,  size,  web_safe,  is_date,  is_string,  word_list,  seq_last_index_of,  node_namespace,  string,  keys,  values,  seq_index_of,

Comment: "keep_before" built-in is available since FreeMarker 2.3.21.  Maybe you are using some rather old FreeMarker version there.

Comment: Is this the version ? <office:document-settings xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:config="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:config:1.0" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" office:version="1.2">

Comment: What can i use then ?

Comment: No, you  can't use it. It is an old version. Try this `[#list value?split(",") as sValue]
[#if (sValue?index = 0)]
[#assign i= sValue /]
[#else]
[#assign d= sValue /]
[/#if]
[/#list]` instead of keep_before and keep_after

Comment: and if i want to add it in macro ? like this ? [#macro arrondi2decimalestest value] [#list value?split(",") as sValue] [#if (sValue?index = 0)] [#assign i= sValue /] [#else] [#assign d= sValue /] [/#if] [/#list] [/#macro] because i m having the same error as before

Comment: What error? "Found split, expecting one of: "/ split method is supported for sure

Comment: java.rmi.RemoteException: Error on line 504, column 41, in template content.xml Found keep_before, expecting one of: date, is_directive, parent, js_string, j_string, replace, uncap_first, float, right_pad, is_transform, number, datetime, node_type, split, is_hash, trim, children, has_content, is_sequence, xml, html, ancestors, new, last, byte, double, left_pad, sort, matches, capitalize, contains, eval, lower_case, size, web_safe, is_date, is_string, word_list, seq_last_index_of, node_namespace, string, keys, values, seq_index_of

Comment: You have made a mistake while changing your code. I told you yo replace `[#assign i = value?keep_before(",") /] [#assign d = value?keep_after(",") /]` with `[#list value?split(",") as sValue] [#if (sValue?index = 0)] [#assign i= sValue /] [#else] [#assign d= sValue /] [/#if] [/#list]` . This way it can't throw "Found keep_before, expecting one of: " error, because there is no "keep_before" in the code